# Retrain a SavedModel in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, resuming-training

Is there any example of retraining a SavedModel? In many places they claim it is possible, instead of using checkpoints, but not examples provided. When I have tried to carried out, the variables of the model remain fixed:

```
...
model_save_path = "test.pb"

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as net:
        ...
        for e in range(epochs):
            # Train the model
            ...
            builder = saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(model_save_path)    
            signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'myInput': X, 'errorInput': Y},
                                                  outputs={'myOutput': out, 'errorOutput': mse})
            builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=net,
                                 tags=[tag_constants.TRAINING],
                                 signature_def_map={'predict': signature})
            builder.save()

            print(error)
```

The code above trains the model, stores every interaction in a model and print the associated error. The code has an output where the error is improving:

2773.6885

291.35968

263.40912

255.27612

When we load it again, and we try to train it, the error stays the same:

```
...
# Load the model
model_save_path = "test.pb"
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(net, ["train"], model_save_path)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
...    

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as net:
        ...
        for e in range(epochs):
            # Train the model
            ...

            builder = saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(model_save_path)    
            signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'myInput': X, 'errorInput': Y},
                                                  outputs={'myOutput': out, 'errorOutput': mse})
            builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=net,
                                 tags=[tag_constants.TRAINING],
                                 signature_def_map={'predict': signature})
            builder.save()

            print(error)
```

The output is always the error from the initial training:

255.27612

255.27612

255.27612

255.27612